# Doctrine Custom MariaDB Platform

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine, mariadb

I've created `CustomDbPlatform` extending `MySqlPlatform` based on existing `MariaDb1027Platform` with custom `getDefaultValueDeclarationSQL` method. I can't extend `MariaDbPlatform` since it's a final class.

```
class CustomDbPlatform extends MySqlPlatform
{
    public function getJsonTypeDeclarationSQL(array $column): string
    {
        return 'LONGTEXT';
    }

    protected function getReservedKeywordsClass(): string
    {
        return MariaDb102Keywords::class;
    }

    protected function initializeDoctrineTypeMappings(): void
    {
        parent::initializeDoctrineTypeMappings();

        $this->doctrineTypeMapping['json'] = Types::JSON;
    }

    public function getDefaultValueDeclarationSQL($column): string
    {
        if (isset($column['default'], $column['type'])) {
            $default = $column['default'];
            $type = $column['type'];

            if ($type instanceof DateTimePrecisionType && stripos($default, $this->getCurrentTimestampSQL()) !== false) {
                if (isset($column['length']) && $column['length'] > 0 && $column['length'] < 255) {
                    return ' DEFAULT ' . sprintf('%s(%d)', $this->getCurrentTimestampSQL(), $column['length']);

                }

                return ' DEFAULT ' . $this->getCurrentTimestampSQL();
            }
        }

        return parent::getDefaultValueDeclarationSQL($column);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, during schema update Doctrine forces to update basically whole schema with new table column definitions. This problem is caused by `MySqlSchemaManager` which checks specifically for `MariaDb1027Platform`.

```
if ($this->_platform instanceof MariaDb1027Platform) {
        $columnDefault = $this->getMariaDb1027ColumnDefault($this->_platform, $tableColumn['default']);
    } else {
        $columnDefault = $tableColumn['default'];
    }
```

How can I make Doctrine to recognize my `CustomDbPlatform` as `MariaDb1027Platform`? Making custom SchemaManager seems to be an overkill.

**Using**

- Symfony 4.4
- Doctrine 2
- MariaDB 10.3

Comment: Would extending `MySqlSchemaManager` and overriding only `_getPortableTableColumnDefinition` method work? Perhaps  less overkill but seems anything else would require changes from Doctrine library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to extend `MariaDb1027Platform`, the only way is:

1. copy the platform class file from https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/3.1.x/src/Platforms/MariaDb1027Platform.php ,
2. place is into your project
3. remove the `final` kw
4. load this file before the class is autoloaded from DBAL lib - you can use composer autoload `files` section

Also, I have created PR https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/pull/4909 to see if the maintainers want to support this officially.